# How to export a specific band from an image collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to export a single band from an image collection as a geotiff file. I am trying following script and each time it is failing.

```
  // Add the shapefile
  var Tawi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/dsbishtae/Tawi/Boundary");      
  var visParams = {color: 'yellow'}; 
  var nameLayer = 'Tawi'; 
  var shown = true; 
  var opacity = 0.4; 
  
  Map.addLayer(Tawi, visParams, nameLayer, shown, opacity);  
  Map.centerObject(Tawi);
  
  // Load an image **collection**.
  var LC = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V/Global")
                              .select('discrete_classification')
                              .filterBounds(Tawi)
                              .map(function(image){return image.clip(Tawi)});

  var visualization = {bands: ['discrete_classification'],
                       min: 0,
                       max: 200,
                       palette: ["282828", "FFBB22", "FFFF4C", "F096FF", "FA0000", "B4B4B4",
                                "F0F0F0", "0032C8",   "0096A0", "FAE6A0", "4E751F", "4E751F",
                                "4E751F", "4E751F", "4E751F", "4E751F","A0DC00", "A0DC00",
                                 "A0DC00", "A0DC00", "A0DC00", "A0DC00","000080"]};

 print(LC)
 Map.addLayer(LC, visualization, 'Landcover');

 Export.image.toDrive({image: LC.select('discrete_classification'),
                       description:'imageToDriveExample',
                       folder:'/gee_files',
                       region:Tawi.geometry().bounds(),
                       scale:100,
                       maxPixels:1e13})
```

**discrete_classification** is the band which I want to export. I am aware that the way I am using  `Export.image.toDrive` is incorrect. I could not get any way to write it correctly. How to do it?

```
Export.image.toDrive({image: LC.select('discrete_classification'),
                       description:'imageToDriveExample',
                       folder:'/gee_files',
                       region:Tawi.geometry().bounds(),
                       scale:100,
                       maxPixels:1e13})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to export an `imageCollection`. You can only export single images with `Export.image.toDrive`. For your specific case, it is just an `ee.ImageCollection` consisting of one `ee.Image`, thus you can simply use `.first()` to get that image from the collection.

```
 Export.image.toDrive({image: LC.select('discrete_classification').first(),
                       description:'imageToDriveExample',
                       folder:'/gee_files',
                       region:Tawi.geometry().bounds(),
                       scale:100,
                       maxPixels:1e13})
```